# Using results from select query as parameters for insert select query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-event

I have a `SELECT` query which returns all matching rows added between 12 and 16 hours ago. It may return 0, 1, or multiple rows.

```sql
SELECT
  service,
  service_host_name,
  time,
  reports_added
FROM
  detections
WHERE
  reports_added = 0
  AND time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 16 HOUR)
  AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR);
```

```sql
+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| service       | service_host_name | time                | reports_added |
+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| instagram.com | instagram         | 2020-10-29 08:41:25 |             1 |
| instagram.com | instagram         | 2020-10-29 08:41:25 |             0 |   
| twitter.com   | twitter           | 2020-10-29 03:41:25 |             0 |
| twitter.com   | twitter           | 2020-10-28 17:00:11 |             0 |
| twitter.com   | twitter           | 2020-10-29 15:01:14 |             0 |
| instagram.com | instagram         | 2020-10-29 22:04:23 |             0 |
+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

I need to use the matching row(s) from the above query as parameters in the below `INSERT... SELECT` query.

```sql
INSERT
  IGNORE INTO my_detections (
    service,
    service_host_name,
    date
  ) (
    SELECT
      service,
      service_host_name,
      date
    FROM
      report_issue
      INNER JOIN report_domain ON report_issue.issue_id = report_domain.id
    WHERE
      service = service
      AND date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(time, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
      AND DATE_ADD(time, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
  )
UNION
(
  SELECT
    service,
    service_host_name,
    date
  FROM
    report_recent
  WHERE
    service = service
    AND date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(time, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
    AND DATE_ADD(time, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
);
```

All the above queries work well on their own.

Ideally, I would also like to `UPDATE` the `reports_added` column in the `detections` table to `1` after the `INSERT... SELECT` finishes with the corresponding row.

If that's not possible I can just `UPDATE` after completion e.g

```sql
update
  detections
set
  reports_added = 1
where
  reports_added = 0;
```

How can I use the matching rows from the `detections` table as parameters for the `INSERT... SELECT` query?

Eventually, I will be adding the whole query inside a `mysql-event` running once per hour, so it would be great if the answers were inside an event, but not strictly neccasary as I should be fine with that myself.

Comment: Might `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` be more appropriate?  It can handles a `SELECT`.  Be sure to understand the use of `VALUES()`.

Comment: I use `INSERT IGNORE` because one of the columns in `my_detections` is unique.